# add-migration not generating anything

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

So I've tried running "add-migration AddBooking -verbose"

To this class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace HostelBookingSystem.Models
{
    public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 BookingId { get; set; }      
        public Int32 Duration { get; set; }
        public Double Price { get; set; }
        public BookingStatus Status { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
        public virtual Bunk Bunk { get; set; }
        public virtual Room RoomPreference { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However I'm receiving completely empty Up() and Down() methods.

The same thing happens when I remove the 3 public virtual attributes as well.

Can any explain why this is?

Comment: Have you enabled migration using : `Enable-Migration` ?

Comment: The problem I think was caused because I had no DbContext set up that was making use of the class. Does this sound like a cause to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The DBContext class needs to be set up

2) Include the property for the above class in the DBContext

```
public DbSet<Booking> Books { get; set; }
```

Comment: This was the problem I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't generate anything was because I didn't have a DbContext set up for the class I wished to generate a table for.